# Alloy.Globals support for iOS in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Do Titanium appcelerator supports Alloy.Globals.object=value; for iOS because I don't see the Apple logo in intellisence when I type **Alloy.**

[image]

I'm worried if it is not supported, then I might not be able to use this as global functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it gives me the value in iPhone (iOS) that means it also support Apple, but I don't know why they didn't provide with the apple icon.